# Google Sheet: If week is within daterange

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need an IF-statement for figuring out:

```
=If(WEEKNUMBER is between STARTDATE and ENDDATE;1;0)
```

For the sake of testing lets say:

A1 = Startdate

B1 = Enddate

C1 = Weeknumber

D1 = IF-statement

Answer (score 1):

D1 using WEEKNUM() function:

```
=if(and(weeknum(A1) <= C1; C1 <= weeknum(B1))=true; 1; 0)
```

For example:

```
__|     A    |     B     |     C     |      D     |
1 | 1/1/2016 | 1/16/2016 |     2     |      1     |
2 | 1/1/2016 | 1/16/2016 |     4     |      0     |
```